# iPod doesn't appear in iTunes after being used as Windows hard disk

Tags: itunes, ipod-classic

I hope you can help me with my iPod Classic 6th generation 160 GB, 2007.
Few months ago I used my iPod to store my files from Windows. I had to format the iPod to use in order to save my information.

Now I want to use it to listen to my music, but I can't, because iTunes doesn't show it as a connected device. It does however, appear in Finder. Also in Windows, it can be read and written.

The format of the disk is ExFat.

I've tried to run in diagnostic mode, it seems that it is OK with values of IO. I reset many times also. Restarting the computer too.

Comment: Are you trying to access the iPod from iTunes in OS X or iTunes on Windows? The question is a bit confusing, as you didn't specify which, but it seems like you're on OS X?

Comment: I have to access from OSX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Disk Utility (`/Applications/Utilities/Disk Utility`), click on your iPod in the sidebar. Select "Erase" from the tabs in the center. Enter a name for the disk, then from the dropdown, select any of the 'Mac OS X' options.
Click the "Erase" button in the right hand bottom corner. ***This will delete all your data on the iPod***
Wait for it to finish formatting, and you should be good to go!

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. I've tried it before, but doesn't work without a name for.

Comment: Good! Glad it works for ya!

Answer (score 1):

Isai, format the iPod. Go to either Launchpad or Spotlight and open up "Disk Utility". **[Applications/Utilities]**

Now select / click your iPod and type in any name. Now click "Erase" and it will start formatting / erasing.

---

## *This Will delete all of your Data on your iPod!*

---

**Make sure there is no portable / usb cable connected to the iPod during this process!**